# Flutter Scroll with fixed start end end point

Tags: flutter

I want to create a scroll that scrolls from one fixed point to another. With Positioned I can draw an Image to an absolute position and I want a scroll that works in a similar way. A bidirectional scroll that has coordinates where it should stop scrolling and isn't sized by the Widges inside it.

As an example it should be able to scroll to the top of the first image that has an absolute position.

It is supposed to be a bidirectional infinity scroll, without memory leaks. I want to remove and add images above without messing up the scrollprogress. That’s why I chose absolute positions for the images and want to know how to make it scrollable.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 1500,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -100,
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        left: 0,
        child: Image.network("https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg")),
      Positioned(
        top: 400,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 0,
        child: Image.network("https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg")),
      Positioned(
        top: 900,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 0,
        child: Image.network("https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg"))
    ]),
));
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to get, could you update the questions with more detail and it would be helpful if you could provide an example of the expected behaviour.

Comment: Your question is too messy and hard to understand! please make it more clear

Comment: provide an example of the exact output you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LazyLoading](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview/example) package or [infiniteScrollPagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination). if you face some issue when parsing the list, check out this post [tempListModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988209/flutter-remove-temp-listmodel-without-removing-original-list-lazyloading)

Comment: and how do i remove or add above?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to achieve a vertical (or maybe horizontal) carousel slider for images. If I'm not wrong, I recommend a package that can easily manage your code and save time.

Package link: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: It is supposed to be an infinity scroll in both directions with images. I want to remove the images to prevent memory leaks. I’m not sure how I can use carousel sliders to achieve that

Answer (score -1):

Just import the carousel slider package from the below-mentioned site.

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Then, try this example code I wrote for you. Kindly explore the carousel options property. This package is popular as well as feature-rich.

My code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  final CarouselController _carouselController = CarouselController();

  final List<String> _imageURLsList = [
    "https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg",
    "https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg",
    "https://trade.recosurfaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/100X-PGB1-DBWT-800x800.jpg",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: _imageURLsList.length,
                carouselController: _carouselController,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                  return Image.network(_imageURLsList[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```