# Flutter Remove temp List<Model> without removing original list lazyloading

Tags: flutter, list, dart

Currently I'am learning lazyloading flutter, i have some errors when load _lazlLoadingLoadMore() after endOfPage Lazyloading is triggered. the original List also removed just like templist.

```
...
list<ModelData> dataList = value.data.length;
...

Future _lazlLoadingLoadMore() async {
setState(() {
  _loading = true;
});

increment = increment + 1;

if (increment >= widget.value.data.length) {
  increment = widget.value.data.length;
}

tempList = dataList;
tempList.removeRange(increment, dataList.length);

setState(() {
  _loading = false;
});}
```

[image: first run]

[image: 2nd run]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can clear temp list and use addAll/assignAll
example

```
List<String> list = [];
List<String> listAll = [];



list.clear();// or list = [];
list.addAll(listAll);// or list.assignAll(listAll);
```

then call removeRange

```
list.removeRange(increment, listAll.length);
```

Comment: Thanks sir! I will make sure that all variable must be declared well and use .add or other function instead of "="

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instance like

```dart
tempList = dataList.toList();//this
tempList.removeRange(increment, dataList.length);
```